# How much does a proton weigh when it is going around the LHC at CERN?

Tags: special-relativity, large-hadron-collider, protons, weight

Considering that speed increases weight and the proton is going at almost the speed of light, I would like to know how much a speeding proton would weigh in the LHC.

Comment: you mean mass, not weight

Answer (score 3):

Real quick, comparing 4 Tev to 1 Gev or 900 Mev, about 4,000 times as much as when it's sitting still.